# How to let viewpager response some other gesture in specific page

Tags: android-viewpager, android

I want a function which   the activity finishes when the gesture is touch viewpager  from left to right if the page of viewpage is 0.But it has some comflict with viewpager.So I wonder how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void page(MotionEvent ev){
int action= ev.getAction();
switch (action){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
    pager.beginFakeDrag();
    startPoint=(int) ev.getRawX();
    firstPoint=startPoint;
    break;
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
    if(newsPager.isFakeDragging()){

        final int moveBy=-(int) (startPoint-ev.getRawX());
        movement=moveBy;

        pager.fakeDragBy(moveBy);
        startPoint=(int) ev.getRawX();
    }
    break;
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
    if(pager.isFakeDragging())
    pager.endFakeDrag();
    break;
    }
}
}
```

See if you can modify these touch events to accept a specific gesture. This combined with the current page number can do the trick.